# Prove that the Christoffel symbols vanish in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, connections

Recently I started reading about connections (covariant derivatives), and one of the first exercises I encountered is the proof of  ${\Gamma^k_{ij}}=0$, in $\mathbb{R}^n$. My handout though doesn't mention what's the natural connection $\mathbb{R}^n$ is endowed with, hence I cannot understand why Christoffel symbols vanish. Can you explain me what is going on please, and how do we prove the above?

Comment: This only holds in certain coordinate systems (namely ones where the basis vectors are constant). This does not include polar coordinates, for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can safely assume that we're dealing with the Levi-Civita connection here, which in this case is the usual directional derivative. Since $\nabla_{\partial_i}\partial_j=0$, it follows that $\Gamma_{ij}^k=0$ always.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, how do you prove that $\nabla_{\partial_i}\partial_j=0$? Can you explain me please?

Comment: Open up the definition of direcional derivative, it is a one-liner: $$\nabla_{\partial_i}\partial_j = (\partial_i (0),...,\partial_i(1),...,\partial_i(0))=0. $$

Comment: I know it is trivial, but I have so many questions about those things.. also many of them probably are straightforward or trivial. Like for instance, the notation in your comment in the coordinates means the partial derivative of the constants 0 and 1 I guess?

Comment: Yes, exactly. We're usually too lazy to write $\partial/\partial x^i$ :P

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 4):

The metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is kronecker delta , $g_{ij}= \delta_{ij}$. On every Riemannian manifold, including this case, the symbols are defined as

$$ \Gamma^i_{jk} = g^{il} (\partial_j g_{lk} + \partial_k g_{jl} - \partial_l g_{jk})/2 $$

Here elements of matric tensor are constant so their derivative are zero.

Answer (score 2):

It's by definition: the natural connection on $\Bbb R^n$ is defined as the connection for which $\Gamma _{ij} ^k = 0$ (i.e. the flat connection, i.e. the one without curvature).

Notice, in this case, that

$$\nabla _X Y = \nabla _{X^i \partial_i} (Y^j \partial_j) = X^i \nabla _{\partial_i} (Y^j \partial_j) = X^i (\nabla _{\partial_i} Y^j) \partial_j + X^i Y^j (\nabla _{\partial_i} \partial_j) = \\
(\nabla _X Y^j) \partial_j + X^i Y^j \underbrace{\Gamma _{ij} ^k} _{=0} \partial_k = X (Y^j) \partial_j .$$